# Imagick convert svg to png with google fonts

Tags: php, svg, imagick

I came to a problem when using ImageMagick, I'm missing fonts which is used in SVG. I've done a quick search, but couldn't find an answer that can be used in my case.

My SVG contains something like this:

```xml
<defs>
    <style type="text/css">@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faustina");</style>
    <style type="text/css">@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu");</style>
</defs>
<text x="61.81135214943191" y="111.73005750523703" font-size="55" fill="#9E3E3E" transform="rotate(15)" font-family="Faustina" style="font-family:'Faustina' !important">Test 1</text>
<text x="61.81135214943191" y="171.73005750523703" font-size="45" fill="#9E3E3E" transform="rotate(-15)" font-family="Ubuntu" style="font-family:'Ubuntu' !important">Test 2</text>
```

The user can add more fonts and more text as well as background image / images to svg, but the problem is how to add fonts to ImageMagick while converting the svg to png?

I can download those fonts and replace code to use font-face instead of import but method `IMagick::setFont()` accepts only string.

Any other php conversion method will do to since `shell_exec` and similar shell functions are disabled. If I can, on our test server I will change that value, but on the production server -- which will run this code -- I can't change anything.

Right now, I use this simple code:

```php
$image = new IMagick();
$image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$image->readImageBlob($svg_html);
$image->setImageFormat("png32");
```

Comment: `IMagick::setFont` does not apply. Used fonts must be installed locally on the server, there is no way around it. `@font-face` rules cannot be used. If the converter actually used by IM is rsvg, even a `<style>` tag will fail; all style information needs to be set in style attributes or their presentation attribute counterparts directly on the elements. (Check with `identify -list delegate | grep -i svg` on your production server which converter is used)

Comment: Wel it uses rsvg-convert as command. so it should take `font-family="Allan"` while converting.

have created ~/.magick/type.xml and specified all fonts which i have placed in ~/fonts directory.

if i list fonts with:
`$image = new Imagick();
$fonts = $image->queryfonts();
foreach($fonts as $font) {
    echo $font . PHP_EOL;
}`
i do get custom fonts in it:
AlexBrush
AlfaSlabOne
Alice
Alike
AlikeAngular
Allan
AllanB
Allerta
AllertaStencil

but when converting i still get default font in it.

Any idea on how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution to my problem, needed to include font as base64 in defs.

so it looks like

```
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ABeeZee';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('ABeeZee Regular'), local('ABeeZee-Regular'), url(data:font/woff2;base64,...)
}
</style>
```